# Mudar campo Varchar para Date MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso consertar uma tabela que foi construída de maneira errada, o campo que seria para armazenar a data foi criado como `varchar`.

[image: tabela]

Com essa estrutura não consigo selecionar um determinado período, pois `varchar` são ordenados da esquerda pra direita em ordem alfanumérica. 
Assim se selecionar 30/05/2016 à 10/062016 vai trazer um resultado vazio.

A dúvida está em como fazer para mudar o tipo deste campo para date, pois quando tento fazer a alteração da erro de valor incorreto, pelo fato dos dados que já estão na tabela.

Como fazer sem perder as informações que estão contidas na tabela?

Comment: Você tem  a opção de criar um novo campo no banco de dados para converter esse campo para Date? Ou só que fazer o filtro no where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa converter data de dd/mm/yyyy para yyy/mm/dd correto ?

Se for consegui resolver utilizando esse script abaixo direto no banco .

```
UPDATE tbl_data SET data =
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') 
WHERE data LIKE '__/__/____'
```

Criei um evento e executei o código acima. Veja se te ajuda.
Após executar o código e atualizar as datas mude o tipo do campo diretamente no banco, de VARCHAR para DATE

Comment: O stack snippet é obviamente usado para executar javascript, html e css, ou seja front-end, não tem porque usar stacksnippet para colocar php, c++, java, c#, isso nunca vai funcionar. Aprenda a usar a marcação lendo o Help ;)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, executei sem o where e mudei todas, agora só vou tratar a aplicação.

Answer (score 8):

Até acho melhor usar o tipo adequado, mas o problema nem é ser `VARCHAR` é o conteúdo ter sido gravado com o dado menos relevante antes do mais relevante. Se tivesse sido colocado ano, mês e dia, não teria esse problema. Bancos de dados são para armazenar dados brutos, não para armazenar textos bonitinhos para serem exibidos, isto é função da aplicação.

Para fazer isto terá que adotar passos. Primeiro crie uma nova coluna temporário do tipo `DATE` no banco de dados. Depois rode um `UPDATE` para populá-la com as datas. Então apague a coluna antiga e renomeie a nova com o nome da antiga (opcionalmente).

```
UPDATE tabela SET datatmp = STR_TO_DATE(data_venda, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/ChangeDate.sql).

É claro que se a aplicação espera que a antiga ainda exista, terá que deixá-la. Mas aí tem um problema, os dados novos (ou atualizados) só mexerão na coluna antiga. O certo é adaptar todas as aplicações que o acessam para trabalhar com a nova coluna.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: OK, obrigado pela informação. Eu executei o procedimento do Philip Said achei mais fácil. Más o esse jeito que passou funciona perfeitamente também executei como teste.

Comment: É por essas coisas que eu digo, tudo bem o autor aceitar o que mais gosta, mas a mais votada devia ficar no topo pra não acontecer situações como essa, que uma resposta problemática fica em destaque.