# Como converter varchar para datetime?

Tags: mysql

Como converter uma data em `varchar` para `datetime` no [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)?

Por exemplo:

`04-12-2016` para `2016-12-04 16:00:00`

`04/12/2016` para `2016-12-04 16:00:00`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Mudar campo Varchar para Date MySQL](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136742/mudar-campo-varchar-para-date-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Com a barra(`/`):

```
SELECT str_to_date('06/01/2017 18:26','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i');
```

Com o traço(`-`):

```
SELECT data(str_to_date('06/01/2017 18:26', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')
```

Comment: O update ficaria assim: update conta_pagamento 
set dt_pagamento = data(str_to_date(dt_pagamento, '%c/%e/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s'); 

?????

Comment: @PauloCosta, sim.